# How to make item selected in dropdown list

Tags: php, zend-framework, default

here is a piece of my php code, related to dropdown list creation:

```
$s_t = array(
"key1" => "value1",
"key2" => 'value2',
"key3" => 'value3');
$default_select = "value2";

$attr = array("id" => "name");
$form->addElement('select','name',"Choose your option:",$s_t, $attr);
```

How to make default selected item in the list, according to `$default_select` value?

(when user load the page, he will see that $default_select value has been already chosen in the dropdown list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your code, I guess you're in a controller.
To create a select element, you should do this:

```
$s_t = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => 'value2',
    "key3" => 'value3');

$form->addElement('select','name');
$form->getElement('name')->setLabel('Choose your option:')
                         ->addMultiOptions($s_t);
```

Or with a single instruction:

```
$form->addElement('select','name', array('label'=>'Choose your option:', 
                                         'MultiOptions' => $s_t));
```

It's the same principle if you are in a class Form.

To put a default value, you must use the key, so if you only have a value, you can do this:

```
$default_select = "value2";
$form->getElement('name')->setValue(array_search($default_select, $s_t));
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$default_select = "value2";
$form->setValue($default_select);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "$user" variable? I don't have this one

Answer (score 0):

Easy use.

```
$form->setValue($default_select);
```

$default_select - must be option "key" not "value"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have a lot of elements on the form. I've just tried your variant, unfortunately I saw a blank page.

Comment: try something like this: $form->addElement('select','name',"Choose your option:",$s_t, $attr)->setValue($default_key);

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
    $s_t = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => 'value2',
    "key3" => 'value3');
    $default_select = "value2";

    $attr = array("id" => "name");
    $element = $form->createElement('select','name',"Choose your option:",$s_t, $attr);
    $element->setValue($default_key);
    $form->addElement($element);
```